# Flaky prometheus java client

Tags: java, prometheus, prometheus-java

I'm using the Prometheus 0.6.0 Java client in a relatively simple app.  All I have are two counters and two gauges, and they are exposed via an HTTP REST endpoint, using the built-in Prometheus `HTTPServer`  And I'm seeing pretty flaky behavior.

Sometimes, the counters won't be registered at all (e.g., never show up when hitting the HTTP endpoint), other times the `# HELP` and `# TYPE` lines show up, but not the actual metric.  I'm able to see the flakiness both in my local dev box, and deployed out on kubernetes pods.

To narrow this down further, I have this bit of code to initialize the counter. And I'm consistently getting an NPE in the call to `counter.inc()`.

```
Counter counter = Counter.build().name("counter").help(helpText).labelNames(tags).register();
counter.inc();
```

I tried the above with gauges, and I get the same error.

For context, this is being called from a class `ApplicationMetrics` with the following code:

```
public static Counter counter1;
public static Counter counter2;

static void initializeMetrics() {
    counter1 = Counter.build().name("counter1").help(helpText1).labelNames(tags1).register();
    counter1.inc();

    counter2 = Counter.build().name("counter2").help(helpText2).labelNames(tags2).register();
    counter2.inc();
}
```

And I'm issuing a static method call from a `start` method in my main application launch class.

```
void start() {
    // Initialize stuff for the rest of the app
    ApplicationMetrics.initializeMetrics();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with how the counters are being configured/set up?  I wasn't able to find anything on the prometheus issues list regarding this.

Comment: Can you include a bit more code to add some context? Where is that initialization code and where are you incrementing the counter?

Comment: @Chris updated the post with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a counter with labels (the `.labelNames(tags)` bit), which actually means you're creating multiple metrics. As in:

```
request_count{api="/users"} 15
request_count{api="/groups"} 3
```

So when you want to increment one of those metrics you need to say which one.

```java
counter1.labels(tagValues1).inc();
```

Else, if you actually only want a single counter, just drop the `.labelNames(tags1)` call to the builder.

Regardless, this question (and answer) would have been more obvious had you used a real-life example instead of `"counter1"` and `tags1`:

```java
Counter requestCount = Counter.build()
    .name("request_count")
    .help("Number of requests, per API")
    .labelNames("api")
    .register();
```

Then it would have been obvious that incrementing `requestCount` directly doesn't make much sense.